# Spring Boot start Zookeeper and Kafka Server from Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Until now I've started zookeeper and kafka server from command line before running my Spring Boot application, but now I need to start them directly from code.
First thing is, I've tried using ProcessBuilder inside main method:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\kafka_2.12-2.2.0\\bin\\windows\\zookeeper-server-start.bat",
"C:\\kafka_2.12-2.2.0\\config\\zookeeper.properties").start();
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
```

But this seems not working, since nothing is printed on the console and after a while the application throws a TimeOutException.

Second, I would like to have the kafka server to run after Zookeeper has started; how can one achieve this?

Comment: May I ask why you need to start them from your code?

Comment: @pgras just for convenience and speed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple embedded Kafka test example with spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753051/simple-embedded-kafka-test-example-with-spring-boot)

Comment: If you want to embed  a  kafka in spring boot , try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753051/simple-embedded-kafka-test-example-with-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `ZookeeperExecutor` to start Zookeeper API from "your" java application by giving 4 initial arguments and a thread runner in place. One example is given on ZooKeeper API documentation
https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.13/javaExample.html
and 
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain

Comment: And for Kafka server?

Comment: you will need kafa dependecy in your maven project and have `Producer` and `Consumer` to invoke kafka from java api. one of the best example is given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602797/starting-zookeeper-and-kafka-servers-from-java-application) answer