# Start Zookeeper and Kafka through java code

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Yesterday I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55475247/spring-boot-start-zookeeper-and-kafka-server-from-java) and I'm trying to follow some other answers I've found but they're leading me nowhere. I really can't understand how to properly set up Zookeeper and then Kafka server from code. What I did so far was this:

```java
Properties prop = new Properties();

prop.setProperty("dataDir","C:\\kafka_2.12-2.2.0\\config\\zookeeper.properties");
prop.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:2181");

QuorumPeerConfig quorumConfiguration = new QuorumPeerConfig();

try {
     quorumConfiguration.parseProperties(prop);
} catch(Exception e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
            
ZooKeeperServerMain zookeeper = new ZooKeeperServerMain();
            
final ServerConfig configuration = new ServerConfig();

configuration.readFrom(quorumConfiguration);
            
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        zookeeper.runFromConfig(configuration);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        
                    }
                }
            }.start();
            
                    
             Properties props = new Properties();
             props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
             props.put("acks", "all");
             props.put("retries", 0);
             props.put("batch.size", 16384);
             props.put("linger.ms", 1);
             props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
             props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
             props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    
             KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
             for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                 producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("info", Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i)));

producer.close();
```

I couldn't find anything more than this.

Comment: what's your question ?

Comment: @howie I want to start zookeeper and kafka directly from java code without using cmd line

Comment: So you want embedded a zookeeper and kafka in your server ?

Comment: Basically yes, I'm working with localhost and until now I've always started them from command line

Comment: There is zero sense in what you're trying to do. Start your Zookeeper and Kafka separately as is intended.

Comment: @daniu what do you mean? I'm trying to start them separately from code but this is all I got until now

Comment: No, you're trying to start them within threads in your application. Start them in separate processes, like you would have when you started them from the CL.

Comment: I've tried that by using ProcessBuilder, but it doesn't start the processes and I don't know how to specify that Kafka server process has to start after the other one is correctly started

Answer (score 1):

Using the `*-server-start` commands would be highly recommended... They setup the classpath correctly.

Otherwise, looks like you are trying to write just simple tests, and libraries exist already for Embedded Kafka. e.g. https://github.com/embeddedkafka/embedded-kafka or [using Docker](https://www.testcontainers.org/usage/kafka_containers.html)

Comment: Hi, not I'm not writing tests, I simply want to start them directly from java when I start the program... anyway thank you for the hint

Comment: You can still use the same concepts if you look into the source code of those classes. For Kafka, the main class is `KafkaServerStartable`... And Junit is not required, just a different way to have a main method. You can see another example here https://gist.github.com/fjavieralba/7930018 ... In your question, you only started Zookeeper, not Kafka, so the KafkaProducer wouldn't be working.